# How to retain a row in a dataframe with similar values in two different column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, similarity

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID  estimation1   estimation2
A   0.0234         0.0220
A    0.0234            3
A   0.0234         0.034
B   -0.005         -1.89
B   -0.005         0.03
B   -0.005       -0.0052 
C   0.10         -0.00067
C   0.10        -0.98
C   0.10         0.11
```

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), estimation1 = c(0.0234, 0.0234, 0.0234, -0.005, -0.005, -0.005, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10), estimation2 = c(0.022, 3, 0.034, -1.89, 0.03, -0.0052, -0.00067, -0.98, 0.11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I would like to retain only the row in which estimation1 and estimation2 are quite similar, in this case only the first row, with the following output:

```
ID  estimation1   estimation2
    A   0.0234         0.0220
    B   -0.005         -0.0052
    C   0.10           0.11
```

Is there a function in R being able to do something like that?
Really thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** After clarification:

One general way could be to group and find the lowest difference of the absolute value and filter thereafter:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(diff = abs(estimation2 - estimation1)) %>% 
  filter(diff == min(diff)) %>% 
  select(-diff)

 ID    estimation1 estimation2
  <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 A          0.0234      0.022 
2 B         -0.005      -0.0052
3 C          0.1         0.11
```

**First answer:**
With base R we could subset by indicating the "similarity" here `0.02`:

```
df[abs(df$estimation1 - df$estimation2) < 0.02, ]

  ID estimation1 estimation2
1  A      0.0234       0.022
```

or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(abs(estimation1 - estimation2) < 0.02)
```

Comment: ok thank you! Actually I have lots of rows, with different ID, so I need to be "general" regarding the threshold... I couldn't use 0.02, as some pairs of values are similar but they are not approaching 0.02

Comment: Really thank you! Sometimes the estimations values are negative. In this case, how can I establish which estimation (1 or 2), should be put first in the difference? estimation1 - estimation2 or estimation2 - estimaion1?

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide a dataset with this situations and the desired output. :-)

Comment: I've just updated my question to make it much more understandable, sorry!

Comment: Just wrap around `abs()`. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant to use the Euclidean distance to filter the "closest" estimations between two columns (grouped by `ID`), and the base option below might be one option

```
subset(
    df,
    as.logical(
        ave(
            abs(estimation1 - estimation2),
            ID,
            FUN = \(x) seq_along(x) == which.min(x)
        )
    )
)
```

which gives

```
  ID estimation1 estimation2
1  A      0.0234      0.0220
6  B     -0.0050     -0.0052
9  C      0.1000      0.1100
```

---

If you use `dplyr`, you can try `slice_min`

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice_min(abs(estimation2 - estimation1)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  ID    estimation1 estimation2
  <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 A          0.0234      0.022
2 B         -0.005      -0.0052
3 C          0.1         0.11
```